# What does the double-splat do in a method call?

Tags: ruby, double-splat

While preparing for the [Ruby Association Certified Ruby Programmer Exam](https://www.ruby.or.jp/en/certification/examination/), I was solving the [prep test](https://github.com/ruby-association/prep-test/blob/master/gold.md) and came upon this scenario:

```
def add(x:, y:, **params)
  z = x + y

  params[:round] ? z.round : z
end


p add(x: 3, y: 4) #=> 7 // no surprise here
p add(x: 3.75, y: 3, round: true) #=> 7 // makes total sense
options = {:round => true}; p add(x: 3.75, y: 3, **options) #=> 7 // huh?
```

Now, I know how the double-splat can be used in converting params in an argument to a hash, e.g.:

```
def splat_me(a, *b, **c)
  puts "a = #{a.inspect}"
  puts "b = #{b.inspect}"
  puts "c = #{c.inspect}"
end

splat_me(1, 2, 3, 4, a: 'hello', b: 'world')

#=> a = 1
#=> b = [2, 3, 4]
#=> c = {:a=>"hello", :b=>"world"}
```

However, I also know that you can't double-splat randomly.

```
options = {:round => true}
**options

#=> SyntaxError: (irb):44: syntax error, unexpected **arg
#=> **options
#=>   ^
```

---

**Question**:

What is the use of the double-splat (`**`) in method *calls* (not definitions)?

Plainly put, when is this:

```
options = {:round => true}; p add(x: 3.75, y: 3, **options)
```

Better than this:

```
options = {:round => true}; p add(x: 3.75, y: 3, options)
```

---

Edit: **Testing the usefulness of the double-splat (none found)**

Args are the same with or without it.

```
def splat_it(**params)
  params
end

opts = {
  one: 1,
  two: 2,
  three: 3
}

a = splat_it(opts)   #=> {:one=>1, :two=>2, :three=>3}
b = splat_it(**opts) #=> {:one=>1, :two=>2, :three=>3}

a.eql? b # => true
```

I mean, you can even pass a hash to a method defined with keyword params without a problem, and it'll intelligently assign the appropriate keywords:

```
def splat_it(one:, two:, three:)
  puts "one   = #{one}"
  puts "two   = #{two}"
  puts "three = #{three}"
end

opts = {
  one: 1,
  two: 2,
  three: 3
}

a = splat_it(opts)   #=> {:one=>1, :two=>2, :three=>3}
#=> one   = 1
#=> two   = 2
#=> three = 3

b = splat_it(**opts) #=> {:one=>1, :two=>2, :three=>3}
#=> one   = 1
#=> two   = 2
#=> three = 3
```

Double splat on a random class with the appropriate `to_h` and `to_hash` methods doesn't do anything that can't be done without it:

```
Person = Struct.new(:name, :age)

Person.class_eval do
  def to_h
    {name: name, age: age}
  end

  alias_method :to_hash, :to_h
end

bob = Person.new('Bob', 15)

p bob.to_h #=> {:name=>"Bob", :age=>15}


def splat_it(**params)
  params
end

splat_it(**bob) # => {:name=>"Bob", :age=>15}
splat_it(bob)   # => {:name=>"Bob", :age=>15}
```

Comment: Not sure if it answers your question, but my coworker shared this article with my team yesterday. There’s some interesting stuff in there! http://blog.honeybadger.io/ruby-splat-array-manipulation-destructuring/

Comment: Thanks @Nate, while this is a great article, it doesn't talk about using the double-splat while _calling_  a method, which is what I was interested in. I'm aware of all the uses of splats and double-splats detailed there :) Regardless, it was a fun read, and thank you for sharing!

Comment: Yeah, I realized that afterwards, but figured it may be helpful anyways. Glad it was!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One might need to destructure the input parameters. In such a case simple hash won’t work:

```
params = {foo: 42, bar: :baz}
def t1(foo:, **params); puts params.inspect; end
#⇒ :t1
def t2(foo:, params); puts params.inspect; end 
#⇒ SyntaxError: unexpected tIDENTIFIER
def t2(params, foo:); puts params.inspect; end
#⇒ :t2
```

Now let’s test it:

```
t1 params
#⇒ {:bar=>:baz}
t2 params
#⇒ ArgumentError: missing keyword: foo
t2 **params
#⇒ ArgumentError: missing keyword: foo
```

That said, double splat allows transparent arguments destructuring.

If one is curious why it might be useful, `foo` in the example above is made a *mandatory* parameter in a call to the method within this syntax.

---

Unsplatting parameters in *call to function* is allowed as a sort of sanity type check to assure that all the keys are symbols:

```
h1 = {foo: 42}
h2 = {'foo' => 42}
def m(p); puts p.inspect; end
m **h1
#⇒ {:foo=>42}
m **h2
#⇒ TypeError: wrong argument type String (expected Symbol)
```

Comment: Hi, yes, I understand how it can be useful while _defining_ a method. The question is, how can it be useful while _calling_ a method. I.e. When will `t2 **params` be useful?

Comment: This is a way to assure all the keys are symbols. `**{'foo' => 42}` will raise. Kinda type check.